# How to make tagless slot template in Svelte like Vue

Tags: svelte

I'm falling love with svelte and I'm trying to do reusable "data table" like component. I want to define headers and rows templates by the client code, so I added headers and row slots in my `Table.svelte` component. I don't want to expose `<tr>`'s tags to client's code for reason of handling some click's events for entire row and so on. So, client's slot should only provide row template of `<td>`'s tags.

In Vue I can use "empty" tag `<template>` which render no tag at all.

How to achieve that in svelte like vue does?

#### Table.svelte

```html
<script>
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    let rows = [];
    let selected = null;

    onMount(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            rows = [
                {number: "01/30/2019"},
                {number: "01/30/2019"},
            ];
        }, 1000)
    });

    const handleSelect = i => () => {
        if (selected === i) {
            selected = null;
        } else {
            selected = i;
        }
    };
</script

<table>
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <slot name="headers"/>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {#each rows as row, i}
    <tr on:click={handleSelect(i)} class:is-selected="{selected === i}">
        <slot name="row" {row}  />
    </tr>
    {/each}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import Table from './Table.svelte'
</script>

<Table>
    <template slot="headers">
        <th>Number</th>
    </template>
    <template slot="row" let:row>
        <td>{row.number}</td>
    </template>
</Table>
```

This is link to REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/92b3a93855124da7b2d991f38353f744?version=3.12.1

Comment: to make it work, you could just use `thead` and `tbody` accordingly instead of `template`. Doesn't answer your underlying question, but might help you out?

Comment: Also, fwiw we did ours with a single slot, so only need one slot to declare your headers and data: https://svelte.dev/repl/6b83696b4fc245dcae1c4fa3374c396d?version=3.16.7. Kinda weird to wrap your head around at first, but the api feels intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

@JohnnyFun's answer in comments worked for me. Adding here with sample code as answer:

Replace `template`s with `th` and `td`:

```
<Table resource="invoices">
    <th slot="headers">Number</th>
    <td slot="row" let:row>
        {row.number}
    </td>
</Table>
```